# The X windows font path error occurs. What should I do to compile?

Tags: xorg, fonts, cross-compilation

I have been used to cross-compile the X Windows.

The X windows font path error occurs. What should I do to compile ?

```
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Mar 24 19:29:28 1980
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
_FontTransOpen: Unable to Parse address ${prefix}/share/fonts/X11/misc/
_FontTransOpen: Unable to Parse address ${prefix}/share/fonts/X11/TTF/
_FontTransOpen: Unable to Parse address ${prefix}/share/fonts/X11/OTF/
_FontTransOpen: Unable to Parse address ${prefix}/share/fonts/X11/Type1/
_FontTransOpen: Unable to Parse address ${prefix}/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/
_FontTransOpen: Unable to Parse address ${prefix}/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/
```

The font path error message as shown below .

In fact, / usr / share / fonts / X11 / path does not do anything.

```
root@test:~# ls -al /usr/share/fonts/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3월 24 19:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3월 24 03:11 truetype
root@test:~#

root@test:~# ls -al /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1099  3월 24 03:12 10-evdev.conf
root@test:~# ls -al /usr/share/X11/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 xkb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 xorg.conf.d
root@test:~# ls -al /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096  3월 24 03:12 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  111  3월 24 03:12 1-fbdev.conf
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  135  3월 24 03:12 2-serverflags.conf
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  275  3월 24 03:12 99-calibration.conf
root@test:~#
```

Do I need to cross-compile any package?

1) prefix=/usr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really not enough information, but from the messages it seems that you have given Xorg a configuration file containing a literal `${prefix}` where it expects an actual directory name such as `/usr`.

That probably reflects a quoting problem in whatever build-script you are using, since a *shell* would be doing the substitution of `${prefix}` while Xorg's parser is not able to do this.

Xorg is reading configuration files from `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, including one containing the fontpath information.  You might see the problem in the file containing this information.  Or you might have compiled a literal `"${prefix}"` into Xorg.  Either way, it is confused.

Further reading:

- [xorg.conf](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml) (in particular [*Files Section*](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading4) where `fontpath` is described)
- [Font configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration) (Arch wiki)
- [cooking xorg dcc, xorg.conf parsing and 20-Files.conf](http://vanilla.slitaz.org/index.php?p=/discussion/1915/cooking-xorg-dcc-xorg.conf-parsing-and-20-files.conf/p1) (describes a problem similar to this: see [comments](http://vanilla.slitaz.org/index.php?p=/discussion/comment/9330#Comment_9330))
- [iMac 11.1: Xorg - black screen](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/42216/) (another, similar problem).

Comment: prefix=/usr, then 
I am cross-compile everything.
That is why it is associated with the fall font.